# Mark of the web, comment doesn't seem to work

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-9, markup

I am running a website locally and it works fine. The pages appear in the local intranet zone in IE9. A customer says they are having a problem with some of the javascript controls not working. They are viewing it the internet zone which I guess is more restricted. I want to run my site from Visual Studio 2010 but have the pages appear in the internet zone so I can replicate the problem. I read that using the "Mark of the web" comment as defined on the Microsoft site will allow me to do this. Shown below is the top of my master page. The line "" should do the trick but the pages always appear in the intranet zone when I right click IE and select properties. I run this from Visual Studio and the site is hosted in IIS. Should I change any other settings?

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="xpThemed" Codebehind="xpThemed.master.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >    
<head runat="server">
.
.
etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" only applies to pages loaded from the local file-system, not to pages served from your local web server.

If you need to force the page to load in the Internet zone, you can either turn off the "Automatically detect" option in the Intranet zone settings, or load the page using your computer's [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).

Comment: The "Automatically detect" option was ticked. Once unticked, everything worked as expected. Thanks for your help, I had wasted loads of time on this trying to get it to work.